# Multithreading synchronization

Tags: c, multithreading

I am writing a multi-threaded application using the glibc pthreads library. I have 3 pthreads - one of them called "scheduler" and other two called "workers" and the main thread.  The main thread listens for events and puts them in a queue. Then the scheduler thread dispatches them to worker queues. The worker threads pick up the events from the worker queues and execute. The problem is sometimes, the event has to be executed in the main thread itself in order to prevent major dataraces. So I need a mechanism to pause the main thread when a special event is received and wait till all the workers have finished their jobs, then execute this event.

In order to do this, I use an integer protected by mutex, whos bits are set and reset by the worker threads. When the worker finds no jobs in its queue, it will set its bit to 0. If there is a job, then it will mark its bit as 1. The idea, is if one of the workers are running then the integer is != 0. The main thread now, when it wants to pause itself for the workers to finish will now do a conditional wait till the integer becomes 0. The worker thread while resetting its bit will check if the integer goes to 0. if true, then it will signal the main thread. At this point, I am expecting that all the workers have no job in their queues and so the main thread can execute the special event. Since the main thread is incharge of queuing event to the first queue, we are guaranteed that no event will sneak in to the workers.

The pseudo code is as follows.

```
int pause_threads() => the one called from main thread.  
{  
  pthread_mutex_lock(pause_thread_lock));  

  while (pthread_states != 0) {  
  pthread_cond_wait(pause_mthread_cond), pause_thread_lock));  
  }  

}  

int thread_resume()  => called after the special event is executed by main thread.  
{  
  pthread_mutex_unlock(pause_thread_lock));  
}  

int thread_set_state_wait(index) => index is id 0,1 for each worker  
{  
 pthread_mutex_lock(pause_thread_lock));  
 (thread_states) &= (~(MTHREAD_THR_STATE_RUNNING << index));  
  if (pthread_states == 0)  
     pthread_cond_signal(pause_thread_cond));  
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pause_thread_lock));  
}  

 int thread_set_state_running(index)  
{  
   pthread_mutex_lock(pause_thread_lock));  
  (pthread_states) |= (MTHREAD_THR_STATE_RUNNING << index);  
   pthread_mutex_unlock(pause_thread_lock));  

}
```

The problem I am facing is that this code is not working always. Sometimes, I see that while the main thread is executing the special event, the worker thread is still active and executing a job. Is there anything wrong in the logic ? Is there any other possible way to achieve this? I have tried my best to search for a solution. Please help.

Comment: Wrong sync primitive. Use a semaphore.

Comment: @n.m. Why would you use a semaphore? Waiting for a condition is what condition variables are for.

Comment: @victorram you need to use any multithreading synchronization mechanism like(semaphore, mutex).

Comment: "*... At this point, I am expecting that all the workers have no job in their queues ...*" Why? There still could be something in the queue.

Comment: For me, this looks fine. There might be race conditions, when there a still events in one of the queues. The main thread stops producing new events, wait for all workers to be idle (for a moment) then starts to work on the event, but in the next moment, a worker can grab an event from a still full queue.

Comment: What programming language is this? And other than you are telling us you also seem to have a condition variable?

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki: there's a shared pool of identical resources which all threads are drawing from. That's a semaphore.

Comment: @n.m. The condition, the main thread is waiting for, is that no other thread is running. The queues where not shown in the example. And if you want to have an unbounded queue, the states "full" and "empty" are the interesting once.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki The other threads also must wait for the condition of the main thread not running. You can do that with condition variables, but why?

Comment: @n.m. There is no need for the workers to have the main thread not run. He is already using posix thread. Why would you add a second library, that you have to use to get a semaphore. A semaphore is a very low level primitive, you can use it as mutex, you can use it to wait for something. Mutex and condition variables are more specialized in there tasks.

Comment: @n.m. As much as I prefer sticking to a mtx+cv solution, I have to admit the attraction of having N-workers acquire a sem-resource top-ended with N upon acquiring a job, releasing it upon *finishing* the job, and the main thread grabbing them ALL before starting its synchronous high-priority event is attractive. At worst you have a N threads sitting on their jobs unable to process them until main releases the sem-pool back to the crew. Or I totally misunderstood the problem as-stated in the question (a tremendously likely possibility).

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki: "I am expecting that all the workers have no job in their queues and so the main thread can execute the special event.". The workers are not allowed to run if the special event processing is running. IOW the workers must somehow wait until the special event processing is not running. I need 1 semaphore and about 7 lines of code to solve this problem. You may call this solution low-level, but the fact is that it's easy to implement, easy to understand, and very hard to get wrong.

Comment: @WhozCraig: you understand the problem exactly like I do (there's still a possibility of a transatlantically-induced high-level simultaneous hallucination however).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky one.  When your main routine is going to go into a critical section, it needs to ensure that:

1. The scheduler won't schedule any more work
2. The workers are done with their work

Both of these require acknowledgement from the other threads.  If you make some sort of message-passing mechanism or use a preexisting one, it might be easier to write this out as a communication problem instead.  With the standard set of mutexes and condvars though, you would probably structure it something like this:

- Scheduler

  1. When scheduling work, increments jobs-in-flight (locked by a mutex)
- Workers

  1. Decrement jobs-in-flight (locked by mutex) when finishes work and broadcasts
- Main

  1. When it needs a critical section, it sets a flag (locked by a mutex) that a critical section is in progress and broadcasts on a condvar that this state changed
  2. Sets a flag (also locked) that entry is in progress and broadcasts state change
  3. It waits on the entry-in-progress condvar for the scheduler to acknowledge by setting the flag to zero
  4. It waits on the jobs-in-flight condvar for the workers to finish
  5. Unsets the in-progress and broadcasts to unblock the scheduler
- Scheduler

  1. Checks before starting work or on condvar to see if main wants to enter
  2. Unsets the entry-in-progress flag and broadcasts to acknowledge
  3. Waits on critical-in-progress condvar for main to finish

When you have all of this in place, main can be sure that no more work will be scheduled and that all work that's in-flight is complete.  It can do its thing, and then unblock the scheduler.

Comment: Compare this with the semaphore solution. Start with the initial value of 2. Worker threads: P; do work; V. Main thread, critical section: P; P; do work; V; V. Scheduler: stand back and watch the show.

Comment: @n.m. Indeed.  However, this doesn't give the Scheduler the flexibility to run as many threads as are required for the current workload, so it may not be as good of a solution in the long run.  There may well be ways to simplify what I wrote, of course.

Comment: Why, it's easy to incorporate this possibility too. In this case e.g. the scheduler does the P/V thing on behalf of the main thread; the main thread would have to ask the scheduler to bring the number of running threads to 0. Since there's already a communications channel between them it should be easy to implement.

Comment: Using the jobs-in-flight idea from Kyle, we can make it even simpler. Since the Main thread is in control of events passed to the scheduler, it can directly influence the scheduler. So the algo goes like this:  1. Main thread increments jobs-in-flight when it passes events to scheduler  2. Workers decrement jobs-in-flight when they process an event  3. When Main wants to process special event it will do a conditional wait till jobs-in-flight becomes zero  4. When jobs-in-flight becomes 0 the workers will broadcast the signal. This would happen even if Main is not doing conditional wait.